# Quarkus application not starting properly

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-rest-client

I have a quarkus application, when I build the application with below command, for the first time process is starting perfectly fine
**compile quarkus:dev -DskipTests=true**

**Logs for successful startup:**

```
Press [h] for more options>
Tests paused
Press [r] to resume testing, [h] for more options>
Press [r] to resume testing, [o] Toggle test output, [h] for more options>
INFO  [io.qua.arc.pro.BeanProcessor] (build-78) Found unrecommended usage of private members (use package-private instead) in application beans:
    - @Inject field com.scania.siddhiapi.resources.RequestHeaders#password
2022-01-12 13:49:51,372 INFO  [io.qua.ama.lam.run.MockEventServer] (build-52) Mock Lambda Event Server Started
__  ____  __  _____   ___  __ ____  ______ 
 --/ __ \/ / / / _ | / _ \/ //_/ / / / __/ 
 -/ /_/ / /_/ / __ |/ , _/ ,< / /_/ /\ \   
--\___\_\____/_/ |_/_/|_/_/|_|\____/___/   
2022-01-12 13:49:51,611 WARN  [io.qua.config] (Quarkus Main Thread) Unrecognized configuration key "quarkus.http.port" was provided; it will be ignored; verify that the dependency extension for this configuration is set or that you did not make a typo
2022-01-12 13:49:52,206 INFO  [io.quarkus] (Quarkus Main Thread) siddhiapi_quarkus 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT on JVM (powered by Quarkus 2.6.1.Final) started in 3.979s.
```

But when I stop and start the process again, process isn't starting...

**Logs for unsuccessful startup:**

```
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[ERROR] Port 5005 in use, not starting in debug mode
Press [h] for more options>
Tests paused
Press [r] to resume testing, [h] for more options>
Press [r] to resume testing, [o] Toggle test output, [h] for more options>
2022-01-12 18:11:41,354 INFO  [io.qua.arc.pro.BeanProcessor] (build-78) Found unrecommended usage of private members (use package-private instead) in application beans:
    - @Inject field com.scania.siddhiapi.resources.RequestHeaders#password
```

When I try to resatrt the machine, and then start the quarkus service it works again.

**pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.scania.siddhiapi</groupId>
  <artifactId>siddhiapi_quarkus</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
    <compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.parameters>true</maven.compiler.parameters>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
    <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id>
    <quarkus.platform.version>2.6.1.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
    <surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M5</surefire-plugin.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-amazon-lambda</artifactId>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-rest-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-rest-client-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-spring-di</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>build</goal>
              <goal>generate-code</goal>
              <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <parameters>${maven.compiler.parameters}</parameters>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
            <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>native</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>native</name>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <goals>
                  <goal>integration-test</goal>
                  <goal>verify</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <native.image.path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner</native.image.path>
                    <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                    <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                  </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
      <properties>
        <quarkus.package.type>native</quarkus.package.type>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

Please let me know if someone has come across similar behaviour and what could be the rootcause for this.

Comment: How are you stopping the process? Are you sure it has stopped correcty?

Answer (score 0):

As @geoand said, perhaps you're not finishing properly the first execution.

In te second execution, we can see this message:

```sh
[ERROR] Port 5005 in use, not starting in debug mode
```

This error message indicates that other application is using the 5005 port.

Looks like your first execution didn't stop and perhaps the second execution can't start because is waiting the http port of the first execution to be released. By default is the 8080 port.

After stopping the first execution, you could try to access localhost:8080 to check if your application is still running.

Comment: I have started Quarkus application and referring to log I got this message Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
but still not able to access port 8080.